# Unable to use jsts types in a TypeScript project (for the browser)

Tags: typescript, vite, jts

In a Vite TypeScript project (for the browser - not Node) I have installed both `jsts` and `@types/jsts`:

```
$ npm ls --depth=0 | grep jsts
├── @types/jsts@0.17.21
├── jsts@2.8.1
```

In my code I try to import the types as follows:

```
import Centroid   from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/Centroid';
import * as jsts from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts';
```

The above generates the following errors:

```
 ERROR(TypeScript)  Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/Centroid'. 
 '/home/[ommited...]/node_modules/jsts/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/Centroid.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jsts` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/Centroid';`

 ERROR(TypeScript)  Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts'. 
 '/home/[ommited...]/node_modules/jsts/org/locationtech/jts/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jsts` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts';
```

My `tsconfig.json` file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
   
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "paths": {
      "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
    }

  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```